# rev_timestamp not valid after upgrade to 1.32

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, media-queries, mediawiki

Hello friends good day

I have a very serious problem after updating from 1.28 to 1.33 and it's timestamp error, which makes it impossible to search and many of our encyclopaedia articles to be displayed correctly.

Please help us

ink of 1.32  :http://wikijoo.ir/32

link of 1.28:http://wikijoo.ir

ink of 1.32  :http://wikijoo.ir/32

link of 1.28:http://wikijoo.ir

1.32.0
PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.5 (apache2handler)
MySQL   5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
ICU 55.1
Lua 5.1.5

MediaWiki internal error.

> Original exception: Wikimedia\Assert\ParameterAssertionException from
>   line 63 of /var/www/html/32/vendor/wikimedia/assert/src/Assert.php:
>   Bad value for parameter $row->rev_timestamp: must be a valid timestamp

Comment: What is the invalid timestamp value?